# unable to display records by last year

Tags: c#, date

I am trying to display records from last year but its not showing any results.

If i take remove the code displayed below then it displays all the results fine.

This is the code I'm working with:

```
var trackFilter = Convert.ToString(DateTime.Now.AddDays(-365));

DateTime fromDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-365);
DateTime toDate = DateTime.Now;

daa = daa.Where(c => (trackFilter == "" ||
                c.TrackName.ToLower().Contains(trackFilter.ToLower()))
                &&
                (fromDate == DateTime.MinValue || fromDate <= c.Date)
                &&
                (toDate == DateTime.MaxValue || c.Date <= toDate)
                ).ToList();
```

I don't know what I'm doing wrong here and any help would be great! - Thanks :)

Comment: What is `daa`? Does it come form database? Can you filter it on SQL level?

Comment: thanks.. `daa` is records coming from an excel file that I am displaying to jQuery jTable.

Comment: `trackFilter` is never an empty string. That's why you get no records with `Where(c => (trackFilter == "" ...`. Why is it never empty? Because it is derived from `DateTime.Now.AddDays(-365).ToString` which is pointless anyway.

Comment: Remember that `DateTime.Now` doesn't only contain year, it goes like `2014-07-24 10:35:23.21` (may be different in other `Culture`.

Answer (score 0):

Just a thought...if you want to retrieve dates from last year you are providing the wrong criteria because you are subtracting 365 from whatever the current date is when in fact you should be filtering by the "YEAR" date part. If you want to get records FROM LAST YEAR your query should go like this...

```
int lastYear = DateTime.Now.AddYears(-1).Year;

daa = daa.Where(c => (trackFilter == "" ||
                c.TrackName.ToLower().Contains(trackFilter.ToLower()))
                &&
                c.Date.Year == lastYear).ToList();
```

This expression `fromDate == DateTime.MinValue` makes no sense to me because `fromDate` is obviously never going to be equal to the `MinValue` of `DateTime` since you're only subtracting 365 days from the current date

Answer (score 0):

If you want only names containing previous years, you can try:

```
daa = daa.Where(c => c.TrackName.Contains(DateTime.Now.Year - 1)).ToList();
```

All the other comparisions are unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
var trackFilter = Convert.ToString(DateTime.Now.AddDays(-365));

DateTime fromDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-365);
DateTime toDate = DateTime.Now;

daa = daa.Where(c => (c.Date > fromDate.Date && c.Date <= toDate.Date)).ToList();
```

That should give you the date filer you are after.

Then once you know that is working correctly you can add back:

```
(trackFilter == string.Empty || c.TrackName.ToLower().Contains(trackFilter.ToLower()))
```

As for the bits with the min or max date parts, I would consider possibly the following:

```
(c.Date == DateTime.MinValue || c.Date==DateTime.MaxValue ||
(c.Date > fromDate.Date && c.Date <= toDate.Date))
```

I don't like the idea of doing a Min or Max value search like that as I believe the DateTime.Min is different to what SQL can actually contain.

Answer (score 0):

if I've had to find an error I first would have to check if the content of your trackFilter String differs from the datetimeformat you use in c.TrackName. (string.format can produce different results by culture)